# How to get data only using $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This my response from JSP, I am trying to get data from the response.

```
$http.get('url.jsp', data).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I am facing "data is not defined"

[image]

How can I retrieve the data only?

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing the **request** `data` field with **response** `data`.  According to the [AngularJS $http API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> and request data must be passed in for POST/PUT requests [concerning] `$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Instead of using the **request** `data` field you listed, you should add a parameter to your `successCallback` for the **response** `data`.

Here's some example code I've written:

```
$http.get('/categories/graph')
      .then(function successCallback(res) {
         $scope.scopeGraph = res.data;
      }, function errorCallback(err) {
         console.log("Error: " + angular.toJson(err));
      });
```

Notice how I read the data from the `res` variable in the `successCallback`, and don't have to include **request** `data` for a `get`.

Comment: Thanks sir. I am confusing the request data field with response data. According to the AngularJS $http API:

Comment: I'm glad I can help.  Two fields with the same name and general purpose can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code syntax for $http.get, it should be working fine:

```
$http.get('url.jsp').then(
  // successCallback
  function(successResponse) {
    // here you can access data got in response as:
    var data = successResponse.data;        
    console.log(data);
  },
  // error callback
  function(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse);
  });
```

For more details, read AngularJs Doc:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Other helpful link: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp